# Frage zum deutschen V2-Satzbau

Tags: word-order

Ich habe gerade den [Wikipedia-Artikel über die V2-Stellung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2-Stellung) gelesen. Darin wird nachvollziehbar behauptet, dass in deutschen Sätzen (zumindest in *Kernsätzen*) das finite Verb immer das zweite Feld des Satz besetzt. Am Ende des Abschnittes *Abgrenzung vom Wortstellungsmuster SVO* steht aber dieser Satz:

> Hans (S) Äpfel (O) kaufen (V) zu lassen … wäre leichtsinnig.

Dieser Satz dient als Beispiel dafür, dass infinite Verbformen (hier: »kaufen«, »lassen«) niemals das zweite Feld besetzen können. Die Bezeichnungen (S), (O) und (V) legen nahe, dass die unmittelbar davor stehenden Wörter **S**ubjekt, **O**bjekt bzw. **V**erb sind.

Demzufolge wäre *Hans* das Subjekt an Position 1, *Äpfel* ein Objekt an Position 2 und  *kaufen* ein (infinitives) Verb an Position 3, womit offenbar belegt werden soll, dass das infinitive Verb eben nicht an Position 2 stehen kann.

Das scheint mir aber ein Wurm drinnen zu sein.

- *Hans* ist nicht das Subjekt des Satzes, denn *Hans* steht im Akkusativ und kann daher kein Subjekt sein: »*Wen* Äpfel kaufen zu lassen wäre leichtsinnig?«
- Der Satz enthält ein finites Verb: »wäre«. Wenn schon *kaufen* auf Position 3 steht, kann das nachfolgende »wäre« nicht die Position 2 inne haben, die ihm als finites Verb aber zustünde.

Man kann aber postulieren, dass »wäre« die Position 2 einnimmt. Dann steht auf Position 1 diese ganze, aus 5 Wörtern bestehende Phrase:

> {Hans Äpfel kaufen zu lassen} = Position 1

Meine Fragen:

- Ist das so? (Steht an Position 1 eine Fünf-Wort-Phrase?)
- Bilden diese fünf Wörter gemeinsam das Subjekt des Satzes?
- Was ist von den Bezeichnungen (S), (O) und (V) im Original-Satz im Wikipedia-Artikel zu halten?

Comment: Der eigentliche Satz lautet: *Es wäre leichtsinnig, Hans Äpfel kaufen zu lassen.* Stellt man um, tritt der gesamte Infinitivsatz an die Stelle des Ersatzsubjektes *Es*.

Comment: Ich erkenne, dass dein Satz dieselbe Aussage transportiert, erkenne aber nicht, warum du ihn als den »*eigentlichen*« (ich verstehe das als »*ursprünglichen*«) Satz bezeichnest, wenn er doch ein *Ersatz*-Subjekt enthält. Wäre nicht jener Satz, der ohne Ersatz auskommt, der *eigentlichere*?

Comment: Der Infinitivsatz als Subjekt ist erheblich seltener als das Ersatzsubjekt es. Das spielt hier aber ohnehin keine Rolle, denn das von dir zitierte Beispiel taugt nicht zur Nicht-Demonstration der V2-Stellung, da wie schon geschrieben der Inifitivsatz als Ganzes das Subjekt des Beispiels darstellt. Der Beispielsatz folgt dem Bau Subjekt-ist-Prädikativ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es liegen hier zwei Sätze vor:

1. Der Infinitivsatz *Hans Äpfel kaufen zu lassen.*
2. Der finite Satz *{etwas} wäre leichtsinnig.*

Nun ist der Infinitvsatz ist ein Nebensatz des finiten Satz. Er fungiert als Subjekt des finiten Satzes. Also lässt er sich auch durch ein anderes Wort wie *etwas, das* oder *es* ersetzen.

Im finiten Satz steht also das Verb *wäre* ganz normal an zweiter Stelle. Infinitivsätze haben im Deutschen kein Subjekt.

Übrigens wird das Deutsche in einigen Grammatiktheorien als SOV-Sprache beschrieben. Diese zugrundeliegende Struktur werde durch zwei Satzgliedverschiebungen verschleiert: Erstens die Verschiebung des finiten Verbteils an den Anfang, und zweitens in Deklarativsätzen die Verschiebung des thematischen Satzglieds vor das finite Verb. Die zugrundeliegende Struktur zeige sich jedoch in infiniten Konstruktionen wie Infinitivsätzen («Hans Äpfel kaufen zu lassen») oder erweiterten Infinitiven («jemandem einen Drink kaufen»).

Comment: Dass Deutsch eine verkappte SOV-Sprache ist, wird auch in dem in der Frage verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel beschrieben, und erscheint mir sogar sehr plausibel. Ich habe diese Information sehr interessant gefunden, weil sie mir neu war, und einen tiefen Blick in die grundlegende Struktur unserer Sprache erlaubt.

Answer (score 1):

Deine Analyse des Satzes ist richtig, aber nicht, worum es dem Autor geht. Die Bezeichnungen beziehen sich auf den Basissatz

> Hans kauft Äpfel.

Hier steht das Verb „kauft“ an zweiter Stelle. Der Autor stellt nun heraus, dass es im Deutschen keine Konstruktion gebe, bei der daraus „Hans kaufen Äpfel“ würde (mit „kaufen“ als Infinitiv und Hans immer noch dem Kaufenden), und kontrastiert dies mit dem Englischen.

Ich finde den Text auch nicht übermäßig klar, das kann aber auch daran liegen, dass er versucht, etwas zu beschreiben, dass es eben nicht gibt.